# Invalid column for SELECT with OVER

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 1,
       row_number() over (partition by lower(X), lower(Y) order by X DESC) AS rn
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE rn = 1
```

When I run it, I get a error `Invalid column name 'rn'.`.

I don't understand why I'm getting this as `rn` is defined in the `SELECT` portion.

I've tried replacing the `WHERE` with a `HAVING` too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WHERE` runs **before** the window function. So run the whole thing in a derived table.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
  SELECT 1, 
    row_number() over (
      partition by lower(X), lower(Y) order by X DESC
    ) AS rn
  FROM dbo.MyTable
) AS t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Ah, OK.  that was actually the form I was trying to avoid.  I wanted to filter the inner query down before passing it to the outer query.  Still, if one can't then I'll find another way top make it run faster.

Comment: @BanksySan: the derived table is only syntactic sugar. It will not have any impact on the performance.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Glad I learned that quickly then before running up the wrong tree too far!  Cheers